# How get result from php the same on java?

Tags: java, php

Why on php  this `printf((2376995291 - 141 * 16777216) / 65535)` on

> result  174.0724040589.

On Java `System.out.println((2376995291L - 141 * 16777216) / 65535)`

> result  65711 .

Why its two different result and how get result PHP on Java , i need get  **174** on java.

Comment: `141 * 16777216` is too big for an `int`. `141 * 16777216L` will do the calculation as a long instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println((2376995291L - 141L * 16777216L) / (double)65535);
```

`141 * 16777216` will technically overflow since it's greater than 2^31 - 1. So, make them as long numbers to avoid overflow and you could typecast the denominator if you like to get the result with decimal points as well.

Answer (score 1):

**In java Try this**

```
System.out.println((2376995291L - 141 * 16777216L) / 65535L);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the number to float or Java will simply ignore the decimal places.

```
System.out.println(((float) (2376995291L - 141L * 16777216L)) / 65535f)
```

Comment: It still giving 65711.07 while in calc its giving 174

Comment: @Mak You also need to tell Java that the multiplication will produce a Long or it will overflow and give you a wrong number. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Because multiplication of is long number.Need to define it as long

Splited into 2 step for just clarification.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Long te = (141L * 16777216L);
            System.out.println((2376995291L - te) / 65535);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`141 * 16777216` is too big for an int. If you do that part of the calculation as a long, you'll get the right answer.

```
jshell> (2376995291L - 141 * 16777216L) / 65535
==> 174
```